# Using R for Creating a complete twitter history

Tags: r, twitter, timeline, twitter-r, twitter-rest-api

Since [twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/building-a-complete-tweet-index) decided to index all tweets since 2006 I am trying to use the twitteR package for R to create a complete user's tweet history. In the case below I am trying to create this for Jack Dorsey. I tried this with myself (short history on twitter) and there my while logic worked great. As soon as I reached the beginning of my tweets the retrieval would repeat itself and the while loop would be broken. For some reason with Jack I reach some point in time 2013 until Twitter refuses to give me anymore information. Anybody did this before? Is it actually possible to create this timeline with old data like 2006?

Thanks for any help or tips!

```
wea_tweets = userTimeline("jack", n=1000)
wea_df <- do.call("rbind",lapply(wea_tweets,as.data.frame))
while (wea_df[nrow(wea_df),8] != wea_df[nrow(wea_df) - 2,8]){
 wea_tweets <- userTimeline("jack", n=1000,maxID=as.numeric(wea_df[nrow(wea_df),8]))
 wea_df_temp <- do.call("rbind",lapply(wea_tweets,as.data.frame))
 wea_df <- rbind(wea_df,  wea_df_temp)
}
wea_df <- wea_df[!duplicated(wea_df2),]
```

Comment: Twitter doesn't grant access to all historic data (with one [exception](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/introducing-twitter-data-grants)).

Comment: @lukeA Thank you for your comment. This [source](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/building-a-complete-tweet-index) from Nov'14 tells something different

Comment: Please read on [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) (_up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets_) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) (_index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets_).